# Instantiate object variables from a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

For example in pseudocode:

```
class Example:

    def __init__(self, dict):
        for key, value in dict.items():
            self.key = value

a = Example({"objectVariable": ["some", "data"]})
print(a.objectVariable)
>>>["some", "data"]
```

How would I implement this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what's the question ?

Comment: `setattr(self, key, value)`.

Comment: There is no question in your question.

Comment: my apologies, i thought the functionality i sought to accomplish would be best expressed in an example. I edited the question to clarify what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign `dict` to the built in `__dict__` for greater simplicy:

```
class Example:
   def __init__(self, dict):
     self.__dict__ = dict
```

Comment: `self.__dict__.update(dict)` should be preferred as it is more generally applicable. Also, later changes to the passed `dict` will not be reflected in the instance attributes!

Comment: A note not to shadow the built-in name `dict` would also be nice.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `__getattr__`, which will be called if the slot doesn't exist.

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, dict):
        self.dict = dict
    def __getattr__(self, prop):
        return self.dict[prop]
```